# Extracting fields from logs using rex

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I am trying to extract few fields from an event log using rex command and display the fields in a tabular format.

This is my log:
`LOG_LEVEL="INFO" MESSAGE="Type_of_Call = Sample Call LOB = F Date/Time_Stamp = 2022-10-10T21:10:53.900129 Policy_Number = 12-AB-1234-5 Requester_Id = A1231301 Last_Name = SAMPLE State = IL City = Chicago Zip 12345"  APPLICATION_VERSION="appVersion_IS_UNDEFINED"`

Fields that I want to extract are: Type_of_Call, LOB, Date/Time_Stamp, Policy_Number, Requester_Id, Last_Name, State, City, Zip

This is my splunk rex command:

```
rex field=_raw "Type_of_Call\s*=\s*(?<Type_Of_Call>\w+)\s+Call\s+LOB\s*=\s*(?<LOB>\w+)\s+Date/Time_Stamp\s*=\s*(?<Date_Time_Stamp>[0-9TZ.:-]+)\s+Policy_Number\s*=\s*(?<Policy_Number>[\w-]+)\s+Requestor_Id\s*=\s*(?<Requestor_Id>\w+)\s+Last_Name\s*=\s*(\w+)\s+State\s*=\s*(?<State>\w+)"
| table msg "Type of Call" "LOB" "Date/Time Stamp" "Policy Number" "Requester Id" "LastName" "State"
```

The issue that I am having is that Only LOB field and State field come back with values, State field for some reason is adding an escape character and pulling the last "

This is what the results look like: [image]

Can someone please help

If changing the logs itself could be a fix then i can do that as well

Comment: One issue: your data has `Requester_Id`, but your regex has `Requestor_Id`

Comment: Ahh you are right, So I matched all the data 1 to 1 with the regex and it started populating. However, The issue with the State Field still remains a problem and the Date/Time_Stamp field isn't coming back with any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @Mads Hansen offered, the slash in "Date/Time_Stamp" must be escaped.  Try this regex:

`Type_of_Call\s*=\s*(?<Type_Of_Call>\w+)\s+Call\s+LOB\s*=\s*(?<LOB>\w+)\s+Date\/Time_Stamp\s*=\s*(?<Date_Time_Stamp>[0-9TZ.:-]+)\s+Policy_Number\s*=\s*(?<Policy_Number>[\w-]+)\s+Requester_Id\s*=\s*(?<Requestor_Id>\w+)\s+Last_Name\s*=\s*(\w+)\s+State\s*=\s*(?<State>\w+)`

Comment: That worked, Thank you. One more question: How would I do if I wanted to total by requestor_id field?

Comment: I want it to come as a new field in the table

Comment: Totals are created by the `stats` command.  `| stats sum(foo) as TotalFoo, values(*) as * by Requestor_Id`.  The foo field must contain numeric data.  The `values(*) as *` expression retains the other fields.

Comment: Okay basically in the log requester_id field would have a value like "UserId1" and "UserId2" I want to get a count of how many times UserId1 and UserId2 show up in the log. They are alpha numeric values. I want this count to be displayed in the same table as above

Comment: I did this but it now only displays the requester_id field and the count, It doesn't display the table i posted in the picture above

Comment: `Type_of_Call\s*=\s*(?<Type_Of_Call>\w+)\s+Call\s+LOB\s*=\s*(?<LOB>\w+)\s+DateTime_Stamp\s*=\s*(?<DateTime_Stamp>[0-9TZ.:-]+)\s+Policy_Number\s*=\s*(?<Policy_Number>[\w-]+)\s+Requester_Id\s*=\s*(?<Requestor_Id>\w+)\s+Last_Name\s*=\s*(\w+)\s+State\s*=\s*(?<State>\w+) | table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip | stats count by Requester_Id  `

Comment: The `stats` command you used returns only the count and Requester_Id fields so that is all that can be displayed.  Put `stats` before `table` and add the `values(*) as *` expression as in my last comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, That is not showing any result. I am putting this stats command before the table  `stats count by Requester_Id values(*) as *` but it doesn't pull any data. But When I put  `stats count by Requester_Id` without the  `values(*) as *`, It only pulls in Requester_Id field without count, In both cases i am not getting the other fields that I want in the table. Sorry I am too dumb

Comment: This is the my stats and table command:  `| stats count by Requester_Id values(*) as * | table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip`

Comment: Also tried this but this had the same issue, No data is being displayed `| stats count by Requester_Id values(Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number  Last_Name State City Zip) as Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number  Last_Name State City Zip | table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip`

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer.  I'm surprised Splunk did not complain about the invalid syntax in the `stats` commands you tried.  The `by` clause must be last; the `values` function takes a single field name as its argument.  Try `| stats count, values(*) as * by Requester_Id`.

Comment: Please don't apologize, I am new to Splunk so I am sorry for so many questions. I see what you did there, It seems to combining results with the same Requester_Id and displaying it in one row, However, What I want is for the rows to be unique and the count for each Requester_id to be displayed as a new field in the table itself.

Comment: Since we've moved away from the original topic of this question, I suggest asking a new question.